# How to insert Javascript loop into SQL INSERT statement if the amount of table rows can be different everytime?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, sql, sql-insert

So I have a table where when executed the table loops through the data and will insert the row of values into the DB. At the moment I am using a basic insert statement (I know about SQL injection is very temp). What I am having trouble with is at the moment I am hard coding  the position of the index in the array. As you can imagine this only works for the first row. If I have two+ rows the next row values won't be the same index. So what I am trying to though is instead of hard coding a million insert statements the table when it loops and logs the values on the UI it should insert it back into the Table at the same exact place no matter how many rows there are in the table. So instead of getInput[3].value it should be getInput[index position of whatever input it came from].value

```
 var getInput = document.querySelectorAll(".vcheck");
for (var i = 0; i < getInput.length; i++)
  console.log(getInput[i].id, " => Input", i, " = ", getInput[i].value);


DB(INSERT INTO TABLE(GENERIC_NAME, GENERIC_NAME2, etc) VALUES ('" + getInput[1].value + "', '" + getInput[2].value + "', etc))
```

Goal is it to be something like this

```
  var getInput = document.querySelectorAll(".vcheck");
for (var i = 0; i < getInput.length; i++)
  console.log(getInput[i].id, " => Input", i, " = ", getInput[i].value);


DB(INSERT INTO TABLE(GENERIC_NAME, GENERIC_NAME2, etc) VALUES ('" + getInput[(position in the table)].value + "', '" + getInput[position in the table].value + "', etc))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @i int = 0
WHILE @i < 300 
    BEGIN
        SET @i = @i + 1
        /* your code goes here */
    END
```

Comment: So am I creating a loop and than placing "my code" in said loop? I kinda understand how this could fix the issue. So in the insert statement am I suppose to instead get Input[1].value I would use just i?

Answer (score 0):

use **Array.from** to convert the list returned by **querySelectorAll** and use **map** method to extract values from each input.

```
var getInput = document.querySelectorAll(".vcheck");
// create an array of the input values
var values = Array.from(getInput).map(input => input.value);
// generate the SQL statement using template literals and the index of the input
var sql = `INSERT INTO TABLE(GENERIC_NAME, GENERIC_NAME2, etc) 
           VALUES ('${values[0]}', '${values[1]}', etc)`;
// execute
DB(sql);
```

Hope this will solve your issue

Comment: Sorry I am kinda confused how will this solve the issue? It looks like I am still hard coding the index positions in the value. The goal is for value to already know without hard coding in 0,1,2 etc